# Rxjs CombineLatest and Object.assign explanation for their usage at the @angular/material source

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have been trying to understand what is happening with this code.

I understand combineLatest emits a value, emit the last emitted value from each observable. 
 and Object.assign copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.

I understand this far, but what I don't get, is how they are used together (combineLatest and Object.assign) in that context.

```
combineLatest(_route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params), Object.assign)
```

This is a reference https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/pages/component-category-list/component-category-list.ts#L28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combineLatest` used to have an optional `resultSelector` parameter where you could map the results to whatever you wanted to. So they are using `Object.assign` as a `resultSelector`. This parameter has now been deprecated and you should use `map()` instead. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/combineLatest.ts#L17

So they are using this syntax to merge all emissions into a single object (I think that's pretty clever way of using `Object.assign` by the way :)).

Equivalent code without the `resultSelector` parameter should be like this I think:

```
combineLatest(_route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params))
  .pipe(
    map(Object.assign.apply),
  )
```

The `resultSelector` function received results as separate arguments `(res1, res2, res3)` while `combineLatest` propagates them further in a single array `([res1, res2, res3])` so that's why I can't just use `map(Object.assign)`.

Comment: So basically they are using a depreciated resultSelector, which is this https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/combineLatest.ts#L240

Comment: Yes, it's not even mentioned in the docs any more https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest

Comment: can you please add a small example for map(Object.assign.apply) and map(Object.assign)

Comment: `apply()` is a standard JavaScript function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1):

Object.assign is used as projection function see [this example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest#examples).

`_route.pathFromRoot.map(route => route.params)` will return an Array of Observable.

`combineLatest` will take latest value of each Observable of the Array and then pass them in the projection function, leading to an object with all params as properties.